# Is there an elementary OS OEM install mode?

Tags: grub, ubuntu

I booted elementary OS to a usb via rufus. I booted it onto my laptop and held shift. At the menu, f4 mode only showed normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

elementary OS does not support an OEM install mode at this time.